# Approach to model solvent in a lattice: e.g. H2O in NaCl

Tags: physical-chemistry, atomic-physics

If a lattice contains a solvent, lets say NaCl and water of crystallisation, what is the condition for a solvent molecule to change it's location?

From my current point of view I assume that such a water molecule is bound to a lattice ion by ion-dipole forces. It vibrates at that location until, randomly, the particle energy exceeds the binding energy. Then it goes to a new location, in the direction that minimizes Gibbs free energy most.

How is the water molecule energy distributed? Currently I use Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. However, Maxwell-Boltzmann is for non-interacting particles and therefore not quite a good fit for molecules that interact with a ion. Further, my chemistry book suggest that ion-dipole bonds have a binding energy of >50kJ/mol, which will in my calculations rarely allow a jump at all.

I ask this question because I'm working on a particle-drying simulation. I intend to use a Random Walk simulation to obtain diffusion coefficients under special circumstances: e.g. if the lattice salvation behaviour is somehow weird. The model must not be physically correct in all details. Even bigger "model" error will most likely be small in the simulation results.

Comment: Good question, but it might be better suited for [chem.SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).